# Documenting code in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, documentation, xcode8, headerdoc

I have seen that Apple's [HeaderDoc User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/tags/tags.html) has been marked as "Retired Document" with this note:

> Important: This document may not represent best practices for current development. Links to downloads and other resources may no longer be valid.

This document was last updated in May. So... which the best practices for documenting code now in Xcode 8 would be? I don't find further information regarding this.

Answer (score 3):

Apple has added new features in xCode 8 to easily add documentation in your code. To do this, simply move the cursor to any symbol and select Editor > Structure > Add Documentation (Command-Option-/). Xcode scans the symbol you’ve chosen and adds a doc-comment outline including named parameters and return types if they exist.

More info on:
http://ericasadun.com/2016/09/16/xcode-8-document-coding-enhancements/